# Javascript ' on.("load", ' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#submit').click(function() {    jQuery("#LoadingImage").show();
        jQuery('#imgRESULT').html('<img id="image1" src="http://johndoe.com/foo.php?username1=' + jQuery('input[name=username1]').val() + '&amp;username2='+ jQuery('input[name=username2]').val() +    '" >');
    });

$('#image1').on("load", function() {
    $("#LoadingImage").hide();
});});
```

The thing is the loading image div, does not hide when the generated image is generated.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that the image might be loading before the event gets bound.  Try binding the load event before setting the src attribute.

Comment: don't use jQuery `load` event for images... read disclaimer in docs about image issues and the many many posts on here  http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Any ideas on what to use then?

Comment: What is this `#LoadingImage` doing? Maybe you can expand what you want to do rather than what does not work. There may be a better approach to your problem.

Comment: search this site `jquery load image`.. a little search effort goes a long way

Answer (score 3):

Since a `load` event does not bubble, you can't use *event delegation* here (what would be the standard suggestion on elements which get inserted dynamically)

So your best shot here is to directly put the load event on the newly created *image node*.

```
jQuery('#imgRESULT').empty().append($('<img>', {
    id:    'image1',
    src:    'http://johndoe.com/foo.php?username1=' + jQuery('input[name=username1]').val() + '&amp;username2='+ jQuery('input[name=username2]').val(),
    load:   function() {
        $("#LoadingImage").hide();
    }
}));
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work.
' Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :  '

Comment: +1: I only noticed after reading the documentation again that it does indeed has issues with bubbling. I removed my answer cause delegation therefore did not work. Nice one.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: I'm wondering about that part on the jQuery docs anyway. A `load event` does not bubble, it won't do it with jQuery nor vanilla javascript.

Comment: @jAndy: I wonder if one could use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) seeing it replaced [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events) which used to be able to bind to `DOMSubtreeModified` which was able to kind-off trigger events after something was added to an element.